# Comparison with an integer from a dropdown list not working

Tags: templating, conditional, integer, comparisons

I'm not sure if this is a bug or not, but there is something weird going on if I try to compare an integer form a dropdown field to an integer in the template. In short, it doesn't work.

I'm working with a dropdown level field for users from 1 to 15 and use conditionals for content:

```
{% set integer = 7 %}
{% set mylevel = currentUser.level %}

My level: {{mylevel}}<br>
Number: {{integer}}<br><br>

{% if mylevel >= integer %}
    {{mylevel}} bigger than or equals {{integer}}
{% else %}
    {{mylevel}} smaller than {{integer}}    
{% endif %}
```

This outputs:

```
My level: 8<br>
Number: 7<br><br>
8 smaller than 7
```

HOWEVER if I replace the code "currentUser.level" with 8 like:

```
{% set integer = 7 %}
{% set mylevel = 8 %}

My level: {{mylevel}}<br>
Number: {{integer}}<br><br>

{% if mylevel >= integer %}
    {{mylevel}} bigger than or equals {{integer}}
{% else %}
    {{mylevel}} smaller than {{integer}}    
{% endif %}
```

Then the output is:

```
My level: 8
Number: 7
8 bigger than or equals 7
```

I checked the database and reinserted all numbers, but nothing changes.

Database had this:

```
{"options":[{"label":"SG1","value":"1","default":""},{"label":"SG2","value":"2","default":""},{"label":"SG3","value":"3","default":""},{"label":"SG4","value":"4","default":""},{"label":"SG5","value":"5","default":""},{"label":"SG6","value":"6","default":""},{"label":"SG7","value":"7","default":""},{"label":"SG8","value":"8","default":""},{"label":"SG9","value":"9","default":""},{"label":"SG10","value":"10","default":""},{"label":"SG11","value":"11","default":""},{"label":"SG12","value":"12","default":""},{"label":"TG01","value":"13","default":""},{"label":"TG02","value":"14","default":""},{"label":"TG03","value":"15","default":""},{"label":"TG04","value":"16","default":""}]}
```

Comment: When you output the {{currentUser.level}} in your templates what does it give you?

Comment: This outputs 8 as you can see in the second example block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use:

```
{% set mylevel = currentUser.level.value %}
```

If you just use `currentUser.level` and assign it to a variable, then what you'll get back is a [MultiOptionsFieldData](https://craftcms.com/classreference/fieldtypes/MultiOptionsFieldData) class, instead of the value you are expecting.

There is a note on the bottom of the [page here](https://craftcms.com/docs/dropdown-fields) that describes it.